# how do I write a projectile-switch-action that changes the current working directory to the chosen project's root dir?

Tags: projectile

I want that when I choose a project from the list presented by `projectile-switch-project`, projectile changes the current working directory to the chosen project's root directory.

I tried this:

```
;; cd into dir i want, including git-root
  (defun cd-dwim ()
      (cd (projectile-project-root)))
  (setq projectile-switch-project-action 'cd-dwim)
```

Did not work. It projectile-project-root does not receive the new path from the project I just chose.

I'd love if I was able to write something like this:

```
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 
'projectile-get-the-root-directory-of-the-project-I-just-chose)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: When you say 'changes the current working directory', what do you want to do with it? open it with `dired`? `cd` changes the current buffer's working directory.

Comment: I just want that after I invoke `projectile-switch-project` and chose a project, a later invocation of `M-x projectile-find-file` will search files inside the root directory of the project I just chose.

Comment: @ninrod It should work as you described without any config.

Comment: @displayname actually without any config, after choosing a project, projectile immediately forces me to chose a file from all the files in the project. If I don't choose a file, then projectile does not switch to the project that I want.

Comment: @ninrod Sorry I misunderstood your needs. I don't know that you even don't want to open a file in project. You should set it to `projectile-dired`. Or just use the default binding `C-c p D`.

Comment: @ninrod I guess I misunderstood again. If you don't even want to leave current buffer, you will need to change `default-directory` which is a buffer local variable. I don't thinks it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: Yeah I think that I'll have to get used to the default behaviour. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The default action is `projectile-find-file`. Change it to `projectile-dired`, and whenever you switch project, you get into a dired buffer of the root of that project:

```
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'projectile-dired)
```